# How to setup customer accounts so that S3 assets remain separate and private (even from root user)?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Background:

I'm creating a security camera service for myself utilizing AWS S3, Lambda, DynamoDB, API Gateway and Angular 2 for the front-end. Camera images will get uploaded to S3, logged in DynamoDB and managed/reviewed via an Angular 2 interface delivered via S3, with API Gateway and Lambda functions handling camera image review features. This is mainly for training purposes and to help keep an eye on my apartment surroundings. The project can flex as needed.

Challenge:

A couple of friends are interested in implementing this project at their property which is making me think about scale and a lot more about security. How does a company store S3 assets for customers while not having the ability to view the S3 assets themselves for their customer's security e.g. security camera images?

Ideas so far:

To keep data separate and secure for each user, I was thinking about using AWS API to setup child IAM users and [AWS KMS–Managed Keys (SSE-KMS)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingKMSEncryption.html) for each user to encrypt images. However, couldn't I use those same keys myself to decrypt other user images? I don't want access to other users' content for everyone's security.

Maybe the encryption comes from the camera hardware/software setup, encrypting camera images before it hits AWS. Perhaps some key or password (password ideal) would decrypt images via front-end or via Lambda when images are downloaded to review. Seems somewhat process intensive, maybe still a great option if I can figure out what encryption to use. Challenge here is that I may still need to store keys somewhere for the decryption process (maybe) which could still open up security holes.

Another idea would be to somehow link separate Amazon accounts and each account can store its own images separately. I seem to find solutions for inner-company cost management with multiple accounts via [AWS Organizations](https://console.aws.amazon.com/organizations/home?#/getting-started), but nothing out-of-the-box for customers for linking separate accounts. I did find Amazon DevPay that can pass on costs to different accounts (a good start), but that seems to have been marked as not supported at some point and I'm unsure if it would help keep data secure and separate.

What is the recommended process of storing customer images at S3 while ensuring the company (or just me in my case in a neighborhood watch concept) doesn't have access to view these images?

Comment: I believe there's a conceptual flaw at play, here, probably related to the fact that these "customers" are your friends.  If I handle data that is *ever* unencrypted, I can see the data. At some level, this can't be avoided, unless the customer controls both encryption and decryption and holds the only key, which creates a substantial risk of complete data loss.  I may need protective and audit controls to track and/or restrict my employees' access to your data, but ultimately someone, somewhere, can see it. But, your account can create a bucket that from my account is write-only, unreadable.

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot thanks for the feedback. You're correct about the partial "customer"/friend conflict. That's related to me not being able to maintain the costs involved with multiple users sending many camera images to and storing on S3 long-term (another topic). I'm also just trying to keep it "kosher" where possible with best practices (still learning). Users holding keys and potentially losing them sounds very possible. Maybe I'm worried too much about keeping the root user 100% out of user content?

Comment: I don't think sharing the service with friends provides a meaningful model with whatever else you might do with this as a product, precisely for the reason that you know them.  Have them set up their own accounts and give you an IAM user with the minimal privileges you require, which might exclude downloads. Then you can hone your skills at automated deployment and continuous integration. :) Note that it is not normal practice for external humans who use your applications (built on AWS) to have any AWS credentials. They'd have application credentials and the app, not AWS, manages permissions.